# how to list out all uplines?

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data

[image]

I want to select "Apple" then output "John" and "Michelle".
I try to run the code but it is not working. Please help.

```
select @start := title as 'title', id, parent
from mytable
join 
(select @start := 0) temp
where parent = @start and title = "Apple";
```

Link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91fd40/1/0

Comment: `hhttp://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91fd40/21` try this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself just in case anyone need it [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91fd40/53) :

```
SELECT T2.id, T2.title, T2.parent
FROM (
    SELECT
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := parent FROM mytable WHERE id = _id) AS parent,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM
        (SELECT @r := 6, @l := 0) vars,
        mytable h
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN mytable T2
ON T1._id = T2.id 
where T2.title<>'sky'
ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC
```